# Google Cloud Run Sudden Traffic Spike Error

Tags: flask, google-cloud-platform, python-asyncio, google-cloud-run, aiohttp

I am using cloud run to service requests sent by my Google App Engine asynchronously. It seems to work fine when I send a cluster of 10 or so async requests. When I send a cluster of 50 async requests I begin to encounter the 500 error "The request was aborted because there was no available instance"

My max instances is set to 500, so I'm not concerned about actually running out of resources. It just seems that Cloud run is not able to boot up enough containers fast enough to handle the large influx of requests. I want to boot up a new miniscule container (smallest possible memory and cpu) for each individual request.

Other than having a minimum # of instances always running which would be prohibitively expensive, is there any other configuration options I have that could help Cloud Run handle a sudden traffic increase?

I've included my requirements.txt below, is one of my dependencies known for causing long container startup? I have a lot of difficulty getting clear metrics from GCP on how long my containers take to start up

EDIT: I've decided to utilize a workaround until I can find a solution. Although I sacrifice some speed, I was able to batch my asynchronous requests into an amount manageable for cloud run to scale.

```html
aiohttp==3.7.3
async-timeout==3.0.1
asyncio==3.4.3
attrs==20.3.0
authclient==1.0
CacheControl==0.12.6
cachetools==4.2.1
certifi==2020.6.20
cffi==1.14.4
chardet==3.0.4
charset-normalizer==2.0.5
click==7.1.2
colorama==0.4.4
ConfigArgParse==1.4
cycler==0.10.0
decorator==4.4.2
dnspython==1.16.0
ecdsa==0.14.1
enum-compat==0.0.3
et-xmlfile==1.0.1
eventlet==0.30.0
firebase-admin==4.5.3
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-BasicAuth==0.2.0
Flask-Caching==1.10.1
Flask-Cors==3.0.9
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.4
future==0.18.2
gevent==21.1.1
geventhttpclient==1.4.4
google-api-core==1.26.3
google-api-python-client==2.1.0
google-auth==1.28.0
google-auth-httplib2==0.1.0
google-cloud-core==1.6.0
google-cloud-firestore==2.1.0
google-cloud-storage==1.37.0
google-crc32c==1.1.2
google-resumable-media==1.2.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.53.0
greenlet==1.0.0
grpcio==1.36.1
gunicorn==20.0.4
httplib2==0.19.1
idna==2.7
intuit-oauth==1.2.3
itsdangerous==1.1.0
jdcal==1.4.1
Jinja2==2.11.2
jose==1.0.0
kiwisolver==1.3.1
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
msgpack==1.0.2
multidict==5.1.0
mysql==0.0.3
mysql-connector==2.2.9
mysql-connector-python==8.0.22
mysqlclient==2.0.3
networkx==2.5
oauthlib==3.1.0
openpyxl==2.4.4
packaging==20.9
passlib==1.7.4
Pillow==8.0.1
proto-plus==1.18.1
protobuf==3.14.0
psutil==5.8.0
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pycparser==2.18
pycryptodome==3.10.1
pymongo==3.11.2
PyMySQL==0.10.1
pyparsing==2.4.7
python-dateutil==2.8.1
python-dotenv==0.18.0
python-jose==2.0.2
python-quickbooks==0.8.4
pytz==2020.5
pyzmq==22.0.3
rauth==0.7.3
requests==2.25.1
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
rsa==4.7
simplejson==3.17.2
six==1.15.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.20
typing-extensions==3.7.4.3
uritemplate==3.0.1
urllib3==1.24.3
Werkzeug==1.0.1
yarl==1.6.3
zope.event==4.5.0
zope.interface==5.2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely you are sending requests faster than Cloud Run can scale and you are not implementing a retry stratgey.

1. Your requirements.txt is unlikely to affect the Cloud Run cold start time. The requirements.txt is processed when you build the container. It is possible that you have something in your code that is delaying responding to requests, but your question does not include your source code.
2. Look at the Cloud Run logs. You will be able to see the requests that responded normally followed by requests that returned errors. Look for a container start message. You can then determine how long the cold start is. Typically, you want your container instances to be running within 60 seconds after the instance start.
3. When sending requests to Cloud Run, implement a retry strategy for requests that fail with 5xx errors. That way when one instance has reached its request limit (concurrency) and another instance has not yet reached a running status, your code can wait and then retry the request.
4. It is also possible that your 500 error is caused by a too small instance size. The logs will indicate what the 500 error is. In that case, reduce the number of maximum requests per instance (--concurrency) or select a larger size.